Bootstrap 5.3.3 _type.scs has waring on compile with Gulp
I am using Bootstrap 5.3.3 in my project and compile using gulp.js
I see warning on every save change.
below message see on terminal.
Deprecation Warning: Sass's behavior for declarations that appear after nested
rules will be changing to match the behavior specified by CSS in an upcoming
version. To keep the existing behavior, move the declaration above the nested
rule. To opt into the new behavior, wrap the declaration in & {}.
I want to remove warning.
Thanks

see https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/40621 - try npm i sass@1.77.6 --save-exact

Thank You... It's Work for me...
Warning clean
